# Group or Conditional statment for comparing rows against each other SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns:

```
ID   LINKID
A    B
B    A
C    D
E    F
D    C
```

I want to include only the ID's that have a linknum to it that is not in the ID field. For instance, I want

```
ID   LINKID
A    B
C    D
E    F
```

How do I achieve this or what would be a good method to scan the two column so that if the linknum is identical to the ID we don't add it into the results?

Answer (score 0):

A simple inner join should do it.

```
select
t.*
from myTable t
inner join myTable t1 on
    t.id = t1.linkid
```

Comment: This doesn't return the output what OP is expecting. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee2b8/2/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two columns: `FirstId` and `LastId` which will contain the first value from `ID` and `LINKID` chronologically. Then, use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the desired result:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c904f/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        FirstId = CASE WHEN ID < LINKID THEN ID ELSE LINKID END,
        LastId = CASE WHEN ID > LINKID THEN ID ELSE LINKID END,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY 
                    CASE WHEN ID < LINKID THEN ID ELSE LINKID END,
                    CASE WHEN ID > LINKID THEN ID ELSE LINKID END
                ORDER BY ID
             )
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    ID, LINKID
FROM Cte
WHERE RN = 1
```